# a function that returns sum of length of items in an array runs faster with first mapping over the array and then reducing

Tags: javascript, dictionary, join, reduce

I thought that if i wanted to sum the lengths of elements in an array, a simple arr.join('').length would be faster than mapping over the array and then a sum reduction. Any thoughts on why mapping and reducing is faster over joining?

Posting the jsperf link here
https://jsperf.com/join-vs-map-reduce

Comment: Have you tried `arr.reduce((r,el)=>r+el.length, 0)` ? And hey, were talking about 5% and thats browser dependent, so why do you care?

Comment: i just wanted to understand. i know just reduce - your code snippet above is faster.

Comment: Theres nothing to understand. This is due to some js engines deeply nested code, nobody is able to give an accurate answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining an array of strings will involve constructing a new string, probably multiple intermediate strings, only to count their length in the end.

Mapping and reducing just involves counting and arithmetic which is presumably faster than memory allocation and copying involved in joining strings.